# $\pi_q(S^n) \cong \pi_q(\Bbb RP^n)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I'd like to prove that $\pi_q(S^n) \cong \pi_q(\Bbb RP^n)$ when $q>1$ and $n>1$. Do I have to prove this by cases? I mean, the cases $q<n$, $q=n$ and $q>n$? Or can I prove it directly? Which theorem or result could I use?

Comment: Another way of seeing this is via the long exact sequence for homotopy groups associated to a fibration $F \to E \to B$.  Since $S^n$ is a 2-fold covering of $RP^n$, you have the fibration $S^n \to RP^n$ with discrete fibers.  Applying $\pi_q$ termwise to the exact sequence, you get the desired isomorphism (when $q > 2$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, if $p : X \to Y$ is a covering map, then $p_* : \pi_q(X) \to \pi_q(Y)$ is an isomorphism for $q > 1$.

To see this, first note that any map $f : S^q \to Y$ lifts to a map $f' : S^q \to X$ because $S^q$ is simply connected. Therefore $f = p\circ f'$ and hence $[f] = [p\circ f'] = p_*[f']$; that is, $p_*$ is surjective. For injectivity, suppose $[g] \in \pi_q(X)$ is in the kernel of $p_*$ so that $p_*[g] = [p\circ g] = 0$. Then there is a homotopy $H : S^q\times[0, 1] \to Y$ between $p\circ g$ and a constant map $c$. As $g$ is a lift of $p\circ g$ there is a homotopy $H' : S^q\times[0, 1]$ between $g$ and $c'$, a lift of $c$ - here we have used the *homotopy lifting property*, see Proposition $1.30$ of Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology* for example. As $S^q$ is connected, $c'$ must also be constant, and hence $g$ is nullhomotopic, i.e. $[g] = 0$. Therefore $p_*$ is injective and hence an isomorphism.

As $p : S^n \to \mathbb{RP}^n$ is a covering map for any $n$, so we see by the above that $p_* : \pi_q(S^n) \to \pi_q(\mathbb{RP}^n)$ is an isomorphism for $q > 1$.

Comment: Do you mean $[f]=[p \circ f']$ and $p_*[g]=[p \circ g']$?

Comment: Yes to the first one, no to the second - at no point is there a map called $g'$.

Comment: The only part I don't understand is "As $S^q \times [0,1]$ is connected, $c'$ must also be constant. Are you using uniqueness of the lifting? Isn't it enough that $S^q$ is connected since it's the domain of $c'$?

Comment: You are correct, $c' : S^q \to X$, so only the connectedness of $S^q$ is relevant.